# Struts2 won't map request param to Integer action field

Tags: java, struts2

Ok, I'm losing my mind here. This should be trivial stuff, but I'm stuck on this the whole day. This is the setup:

**form jsp:**

```
<s:form action="update-po-numbers" method="GET">
        <h3>PO numbers</h3>

        <s:hidden name="programId"/>

        USD: <s:textfield name="poNumUSD.paramValue" />
        EUR: <s:textfield name="poNumEUR.paramValue" />

        <s:submit value="Update PO numbers" />
</s:form>
```

**struts.xml:** (default struts interceptor stack is used)

```
<action name="update-po-numbers" class="UpdatePONumbersAction">
        <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**UpdatePONumbersAction.java:**

```
public class UpdatePONumbersAction extends BaseAction {

        private Integer                 programId;
        private InvoiceParameterVO      poNumUSD;
        private InvoiceParameterVO      poNumEUR;

        @Override
        public String execute () throws Exception {

                InvoiceManager.updatePoNums(programId, poNumUSD, poNumEUR);

                return Action.SUCCESS;
        }

        public Integer getProgramId () {
                return programId;
        }

        public void setProgramId ( Integer programId ) {
                this.programId = programId;
        }

        public InvoiceParameterVO getPoNumUSD () {
                return poNumUSD;
        }

        public void setPoNumUSD ( InvoiceParameterVO poNumUSD ) {
                this.poNumUSD = poNumUSD;
        }

        public InvoiceParameterVO getPoNumEUR () {
                return poNumEUR;
        }

        public void setPoNumEUR ( InvoiceParameterVO poNumEUR ) {
                this.poNumEUR = poNumEUR;
        }
}
```

The form is previously populated with values. I can see from Chrome dev tools that all request params are being sent as expected and are not null. Inside the action, poNumUSD.paramValue and poNumEUR.paramValue (which are Strings) are being set just fine. However, programId is being set to null.  I can obtain `programId` "manually" as String with:

`ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParam(paramName)`)

but I want the automatic type conversion. What am I missing? At least, any help with how to debug this to track down the problem would be great.

Comment: Suggestions for debugging:Enable debug logging for struts packages. Make a simple form where you only keep information related to the problem, ie a form with just programId

Comment: Found it ? What was the problem ?

Comment: Nope :( I was so furious I had to give it a break over the weekend. I'll give it another go tomorrow.

Comment: What is value of `programId` that you see in dev tools?

Comment: Populating action bean is what params interceptor does, make sure it's on the stack.

Comment: @AleksandrM, programId=2

Comment: @RomanC, yup, it's there, I use the struts default stack.

Comment: Where? How can I see it?

Comment: @RomanC, you don't see it, but there is a `<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>` for the whole action package.

Comment: Don't write a code in comments, edit your question and add details. Anyway this is not enough information you supplied. Consider to work on preparing [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

you did not set value of `programId` in your **form.jsp**

```
<s:hidden name="programId" value="1" />
```

OR

```
<s:hidden name="programId" value="%{programId}" />
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" id="programId" name="programId" value="<%=request.getParameter("programId")%>" />
```

Comment: Your `<input type="hidden"...` block helped with me with another problem - thanks.